# How to interpolate an image src in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a photo from an object I received from an API. I was able to get down to the data information, but the image is not displaying in the displayPhoto function. I was wondering what was wrong with this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
import axios from "axios"; 

// fetch api 
// display data 
// display more data 

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchAPI = () => {
  axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
  .then(res => {
    // handle success
    console.log(res["data"]["results"]);
    const indData = (res["data"]["results"]);
    const updatedData = [
      ...data, 
      ...indData
    ]
    setData(updatedData); 
    // console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  }
  
  const mapData = (info) => {
    const first = (info["name"]["first"])
    const last = (info["name"]["last"])
    return `${first} ${last}`;
  }

  const displayPhoto = (info) => {
    const picture = (info["picture"]["large"]);
    return <img src={picture} />;
  }
  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={fetchAPI} >Fetch API  </button>

        {data.map((e, idx) => (
          <p>{mapData(e, idx)}</p>
          {displayPhoto(e)}          
          ))}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put the wrong src to img tag in displayPhoto function. You should check the path and then render img component with it.

```
{data.map((e, idx) => (
       <div>
          <p>{mapData(data, idx)}</p>
          <img src={data.rightSrcl} />        
       </div>
          ))}
```